# Performance in using inline function Vs just typing the code directly

Tags: c++

I'm still learning and from what I know inline function is used to evade "function call" in normal function, which cost performance. But if inline function is suppose to be short why not just type it directly?

This inline function:

```
// header file
// chapter6.h

#include <string>

using std::string;

inline bool b_func(string& str1, string& str2) {
    return str1 == str2;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "chapter6.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    string s1 = "Text1",
        s2 = "Text2",
        s3 = "Text3",
        s4 = "Text4",
        s5 = "Text5";

    cout << b_func(s1, s2) << '\n'
        << b_func(s3, s4) << '\n'
        << b_func(s5, s1) << '\n'
        << b_func(s1, s1) << '\n'
        << b_func(s5, s5) << '\n'
        << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Vs

This one here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main() {
    string s1 = "Text1",
        s2 = "Text2",
        s3 = "Text3",
        s4 = "Text4",
        s5 = "Text5";

    cout << bool(s1 == s2) << '\n'
        << bool(s3 == s4) << '\n'
        << bool(s5 == s1) << '\n'
        << bool(s1 == s1) << '\n'
        << bool(s5 == s5) << '\n'
        << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which one is better?

Comment: readability is a top priority, hence writing a function that merely gives a poor name to `==` is not "better"

Comment: This is not going to be a big deal here, as it is just a simple binary comparison function. However always benchmark to see the difference of your code!

Comment: btw `inline` `!=` function calls will be inlined by the compiler.

Comment: See https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/posts/cpp/ for an embarrassing litany of copy-paste errors that could have been avoided with inline functions or loops.

Comment: I see so its just for the readability and to avoid error... I think I understand it better, thx guys

Answer (score 0):

First, the compiler will inline function calls when possible and when it decided that it will be beneficial for performance, irrespective of using the keyword `inline`. Consider this example:

```
int add(int a,int b) { return a+b; }

int main()
{
    return add(0,42);
}
```

With optimizations turned on (`-O3`), gcc produces following output:

```
add(int, int):
        lea     eax, [rdi+rsi]
        ret
main:
        mov     eax, 42
        ret
```

The function is still there, but `main` does not call it. This is not representative for the general case. The message is: If you care, look at the compiler output and profile.

Assuming inlining the function by the compiler and manually inlining the code results in same performance, the benefits of writing the function are:

- functions can be given descriptive names
- functions can be tested in isolation
- the same function can be called multiple times (ie no code duplication)